# WebhookNotification, BraintreeGateway in sandbox mode

Tags: api, braintree, web-development-server, braintree-sandbox, braintree-data

On Braintree sandbox panel, under settings button have Api page and inside this page have webhooks tab. I create a new webhook with  URL that created for handle webhook.

`https://myexamplewebsite.tld/webhook`

On webhook, I select all notifications (also I select *Charged Successfully* notification) and save it. When I click **Check URL** button everything is working fine. On my logs, I can see Braintree posted data. But if I start a new subscription (with success payment). Webhooks do not post any data to our server.

I am working on sandbox mode. But subscription is created correctly on sandbox mode. Please, can you give me an idea, why Braintree does not post data, abut my subscription.

After i click check url:

[image]

But after suscription done there is no posted data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We contact the support team. They told us that there is temporarily problem from Braintree and after the short time problem is fixed, on sandbox mode.